# Can an Active Directory CA issue certificates for one-way trusted domains?

Tags: linux, security, certificate, active-directory

Our network is composed primarily of Windows servers on our internal domain which is managed by Active Directory (natch). We also have a small population of Linux servers which, for reasons, are managed by IDM. Also for reasons, IDM is set up with a one-way trust to AD (IDM trusts AD) to facilitate user management in a single location (this cannot be changed).

At the moment we have three domains (names changed to protect the innocent):

- internal.dom
- windows.internal.dom
- linux.internal.dom

linux.internal.dom is maintained on the IDM server and the other two are on AD. Since the trust between IDM and AD is one-way, it is not visible within the AD UI. The others, of course are visible in AD since that is where they are maintained.

We are setting up AD Certificate Services so we can issue certs for each domain. However, since linux.internal.dom is on IDM which only has the one-way trust, and therefore does not show up in AD, one cannot create certs for it in the UI. Ultimately, we won't be using the UI anyway since an automated/scripted method will be more efficient.

So, now my question: Is it possible for an AD CA to issue a certificate for a (sub)domain that is not fully trusted? That is, will we be able to issue certs for linux.internal.dom even though it does not show up in the AD UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control the CA; therefore, you can issue certificates for any name that you desire.  You can issue a certificate for linux.bobsyouruncle.com if you so desire.  Any client that trusts this CA should accordingly trust certificates issued from it or its subordinate CAs.

In any event, the Active Directory trust and its directionality is necessarily decoupled from the Certificate Authority's chain of trust.

A great example of this process would be SSL Inspection by a firewall performing traffic analysis - an arguably legitmate use case of Man-in-the-Middle.  For each request to an encrypted website, the firewall in question (usually through a transparent proxy) generates a trusted (but technically phony) certificate for the FQDN of the external resource in question.